# How to use custom function to calculate 'x' in ffmpeg crop

Tags: bash, video, terminal, ffmpeg, crop

[ffmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) have this example:

`crop=in_w/2:in_h/2:(in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(n/10):(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(n/7)`

To make it simpler, I will use named params and only affect output width and position `x`
`crop=w=in_w/3:x=(in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(n/10)`

The result will be the video that is 3 times shorter than original and it will 'float' along the `x` axis thanks to that sin(n/10) function. x is evaluated for each frame and n(number of the input frame) will increase and change the x position dynamically.

I'm trying to create a custom function, which will take `n` or `t` and based on it return some value of x.

Please help me or perhaps this is not possible. I was trying to create a small bash script, which will do so unsuccessfully.

Thank you

Comment: What function did you want?

Comment: Basically I wanted a custom function, which will change X based on time, so it would look like: `crop=w=in_w/3:x=myFunc(t)`

Comment: I got that, but what function? How do you wish it to change?

Comment: Let just say for example (disregard syntax)
   def myFunc(t)
      if (t  > 0 && t < 4) {
         return 100
      } else {
         return 200
      }
    end

The idea is that I want to move focal point on the scene changes. I already know the scene changes times, so I need to change x of crop function at that time.

On a side note, I already worked around this issue, by basically creating multiple videos, cropping them separately and putting them back together. However, would love to learn if it is possible to do without creating multiple videos. Thanks